# Why are my include statements not showing up?

Tags: php, xampp

I have been programming this website and have started using php for the first time. I decided to put some portions of my site into a php file to reference repeatedly. However, it is not showing up. I think this may be a problem with XAMPP because I decided to use a simple case (from w3schools.com) to test what the problem may be.

first my main file to test off main.php:

```
<html>
<body>

<h1>Welcome to my home page!</h1>
<p>Some text.</p>
<p>Some more text.</p>
<?php include 'footer.php';?>

</body>
</html>
```

the footer.php file it references:

```
<?php
echo "<p>Copyright &copy; 1999-" . date("Y") . " W3Schools.com</p>";
?>
```

XAMPP screen:
[image]

filepath:
[image]

output:
[image]

Comment: At the top of the page, write: `<?php ini_set("display_errors",1); error_reporting(E_ALL); ?>` This will make sure error reporting is on. Also do that ^^

Comment: I guess you have some file path issue. First you need to enable error reporting as mentioned in the previous comment. Then you can edit the question and add that error here.

Comment: Make sure that you are running the file as `http://localhost/test/main.php` and not like `C:\xampp\htdocs\test\main.php`

Comment: Chayan, you're right. That explained what was I was doing wrong. Thank you. I'm so used to checking css code by dragging and dropping.

Answer (score 0):

Add `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ?>` to a head of the html file.

Then refresh the page and check for errors. I think you have problems with path

Comment: I did. Nothing happened. Literally the same text as before.